# Como posso converter uma string Html em um arquivo de imagem?

Tags: pdf, imagem, vb.net, itextsharp

Estou com um problema no *[ItextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)* para colocar determinado HTML no PDF, porque ele tem algumas limitações em relação ao CSS. Então pensei em converter o HTML em imagem e simplesmente anexá-lo ao meu documento.

Como posso converter, por exemplo, uma tabela para imagem? (Sem ter que converter todo o conteúdo de uma página)

Answer (score 3):

Existe um componente externo chamado [HtmlRenderer](https://github.com/ArthurHub/HTML-Renderer) que talvez seja o que você precisa. No código abaixo eu gero um bitmap que é a renderização de uma tabela Html. No exemplo eu estou salvando o arquivo em disco, mas você pode anexa-lo ao seu documento.

```vb
Dim arquivoImagem As New Bitmap(600, 600)
Dim pontoInicial As New PointF(0, 0)
Dim TamanhoMaximo As New System.Drawing.SizeF(400, 400)
HtmlRenderer.HtmlRender.RenderGdiPlus(Graphics.FromImage(arquivoImagem), 
                                      "<html><body><table border=1><tr><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr><tr><td>C</td><td>D</td></tr></body>", 
                                      pontoInicial, 
                                      TamanhoMaximo)
arquivoImagem.Save("C:\Teste.png", ImageFormat.Png)

Console.ReadKey()
```

Se voce quiser mais informações pode dar uma olhada nesse outro [post do Stackoverflow em Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832304/convert-html-string-to-image/17835914#17835914), pois me ajudou a encontrar esse componente e a resolver esse problema.

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar o [Pechkin](https://github.com/gmanny/Pechkin), que é um wrapper do `wkhtmtopdf`. Esse, por sua vez, usa o WebKit, engine padrão de alguns browsers, para gerar o PDF. O resultado é praticamente fiel ao que se vê no nagevador :)